# Can't get the bitmapdata from dropped image in Flex Air AS3

Tags: apache-flex, image, drag-and-drop, air, bitmapdata

When I drop an image onto my canvas I can get the nativePath to the image but not the bitmapdata which is the one I need.

In debug mode when I look into the file properties the data is set to NULL.

What am I doing wrong here? In my code `file.data` doesn't give me anything.

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    this.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_ENTER,onDragIn);
    this.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP,onDrop);
    NativeDragActions.COPY;
}

        private function onDrop(e:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            trace("Dropped!");
            
            var dropfiles:Array = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;
            for each (var file:File in dropfiles){
                switch (file.extension.toLowerCase()){
                    case "png" :
                        trace('png');
                        //resizeImage(file.nativePath);
                        break;
                    case "jpg" :
                        trace('jpg');
                        //resizeImage(file.nativePath);
                        break;
                    case "jpeg" :
                        trace('jpeg');
                        //resizeImage(file.nativePath);
                        break;
                    case "gif" :
                        resizeImage(file.nativePath);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Alert.show("choose an image file!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to load the bytearray:

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
stream.readBytes(ba);
stream.close();
```

next, load the bitmap using:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
loader.loadBytes(ba);
```

finally, get the bitmap

```
private function fileLoaded(event:Event):void {
    var bitmap:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.content);

    // finally you have:   bitmap.bitmapData

    // cleanup
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
}
```